# How can I get 8-x random values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a function worp that returns 2 lists of integers.

Where the first list of integers is the result of 8 minus the length of the input list, dice throws.

And the second list is the input list.

This is my code:

```
import System.Random

worp :: [Int] -> [[IO Int]]
worp d = [werpDobbelstenen (8-length d),d]

werpDobbelstenen :: Int -> [IO Int]
werpDobbelstenen 0 = []
werpDobbelstenen x = randomRIO (1,6):werpDobbelstenen x-1
```

Im getting this error:

```
System.IO> :load "X:\\haskell\\dobbel.hs"
ERROR file:.\dobbel.hs:17 - Instance of Num [IO Int] required for definitio of werpDobbelstenen
```

Comment: That code causes a different error from the one you're quoting. Please edit your question to include the full and exact error message.

Comment: sidenote : you can make `werpDobbelstenen` tail recursive :)

Comment: by the way, how does `worp` compile ? `[werpDobbelstenen (8-length d),d]` is not a homogeneous list !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would return an `IO [Int]` value for simplicity:

```
import Control.Monad  -- replicateM
import System.Random  -- randomRIO

werpDobbelstenen :: Int -> IO [Int]
werpDobbelstenen n = replicateM n (randomRIO (1,6))
```

Now, define your `worp` more simply, as one that simply takes a list of `Int` and returns the desired pair of lists.

```
worp' :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
worp' d = (d, map (\x -> x - length d) d)
```

And finally, you can simply map `worp` over the result of `werpDobbelstenen` to get an `IO ([Int], [Int])` value.

```
worp :: Int -> IO ([Int], [Int])
worp n = fmap worp' (werpDobbelstenen n)
```

---

After a little more thinking, I think this is what you want:

```
import Control.Monad  -- replicateM
import System.Random  -- randomRIO

werpDobbelstenen :: Int -> IO [Int]
werpDobbelstenen n = replicateM n (randomRIO (1,6))

worp' :: [Int] -> IO ([Int],  [Int])
worp' d = let n = 8 - length d
          in do d' <- werpDobbelstenen n
                return (d, d')

worp :: Int -> IO ([Int], [Int])
worp n = werpDobbelstenen n >>= worp'

>>> worp 6
([4,1,2,5,6,4],[1,2])
```

In this case, the second value of the tuple is always an empty list for `n >= 8`. You may want to do something different for values larger than 8.

Comment: I don't think I've answered  your actual question; my definition of `worp'` doesn't really correspond to the pair of lists you want. However, I do stand by my suggested definition of `werpDobbelstenen`, if that helped you solve your own problem.

Comment: I like the comment in `import Control.Monad  -- replicateM`, but a qualified `import Control.Monad (replicateM)` is even better.

Comment: Yes, thank you! :) This is exactly what i wanted, but you made a typo at line 7, " worp " should be " worp' "